# How do I return my updated array elements to the DOM?

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm still working on my word filter. I've tried different things, but I'm always getting stuck with putting my updated words back into the DOM. The goal is to collect all bad words, replace them with a string (like ****) and output that in place of the original term. E.g. having the text "this is a text with a bad word" that would get turned into "this is a text with a **** word". I have an array of bad words stored in and declared as `badStuff`.

First, I get all `inputs type = text` and turn that HTML collection into an array. Same with the `textareas`. Then I merge these arrays into `submittedWords`.

I use a function that compares and replaces words as follows:

```
function validateText() {

  // get the values from all input fields
  for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    submittedWords.push(inputs[i].value);
  }

  // add the values from all textareas
  for (let i = 0; i < textareas.length; i++) {
    submittedWords.push(textareas[i].value);
  }

  // loop through the submitted words and if one matches an item in badStuff,
  // replace the original term with a censored version
  for ( let i = 0; i < submittedWords.length; i++) {
    if (badStuff.includes(submittedWords[i].toLowerCase())) {
      submittedWords[i] = submittedWords[i].replace(submittedWords[i], "****");
      //return submittedWords[i] into DOM
      // return? print?
    }
  }

  // clear submittedWords array after each check
  submittedWords = [];
}

validateText();
```

Now my problem is that I'm not sure how to output my results into the DOM, so that every bad word gets replaced with **** whenever `validateText()` runs and encounters one. I know how to replace text within, say, some `<p>` or other tag or exchange/update CSS classes via JS to display results. But here, I have an array with elements from various input fields and textareas that need to be replaced.

Maybe I can't see the obvious.

Comment: But where in the page do you want to display them?

Comment: Wherever the original word was, so in the respective textarea or input field. Like if someone, for whatever reason, entered in a name field: _name: bad word_ I would like it to be _name: ****_. Or in a textarea: _This is some badWord text._ to: _This is some **** text._ Basically like when Office or so underlines a misspelled word.

Comment: You should give react, angular or vueJS a shot. Those are marvellous for this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to store everything in array and then loop twice. Doing so you will leave control to the DOM element.

Shorten your code to:

```
for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    if (badStuff.includes(inputs[i].value.toLowerCase())) {
      inputs[i].value = inputs[i].value.replace(inputs[i].value, "****");
    }
}


for (let i = 0; i < textareas.length; i++) {
   if (badStuff.includes(textareas[i].value.toLowerCase())) {
      textareas[i].value = textareas[i].value.replace(textareas[i].value, "****");
   }
}
```

**On the other hand**

`input` and `textarea` fields may have many words that are in badStuff array so  `badStuff.includes(full_value)` will not be sufficient for you, instead your approach should be

```js
var badStuff = ["bad1", "bad2", "bad3"];
var str = "hello bad1, how bad2"
badStuff.some(v => {
    if (str.includes(v)) {
      str = str.replace(v, "****")
    }
})
console.log(str);
```

**UPDATE**

Final code for you can be:

```
for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    badStuff.some(v => {
        if (inputs[i].value.toLowerCase().includes(v)) {
          inputs[i].value = inputs[i].value.replace(v, "****")
        }
    })
}


for (let i = 0; i < textareas.length; i++) {
    badStuff.some(v => {
        if (textareas[i].value.toLowerCase().includes(v)) {
          textareas[i].value = textareas[i].value.replace(v, "****")
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Your first example works! Thank you so much for that. But you're right, if a bad word is within some other text, it doesn't get detected. Am I getting this right, though? Would `str` from your second example be the value from an input field or text area? Would I include this in my `for loop` instead of the code that uses full values?

Comment: @Raefiel yeah obviousaly. I have updated my answer with your final code. Enjoy :)

Comment: I actually think I figured it out. It now recognizes words within a text even if the match isn't 100%. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score -1):

As long as your element are form fields, you should push the elements instead of their value to the array and the, in your for loop, update their `value` property if needed. Here is an example:

```js
const badStuff = [
  'censure',
  'blacklist',
  'reprehend'
];

let submittedWords = [];

function validateText() {
  const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
  // get all the input fields
  for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    submittedWords.push(inputs[i]);
  }
  const textareas = document.querySelectorAll('textarea');
  // add all the textareas
  for (let i = 0; i < textareas.length; i++) {
    submittedWords.push(textareas[i]);
  }

  // loop through the form field elements and if their value matches an item in badStuff, replace the original value with a censored version
  for (let i = 0; i < submittedWords.length; i++) {
    const element = submittedWords[i];
    if (badStuff.includes(element.value.toLowerCase())) {
      element.value = element.value.replace(element.value, "****");
    }
  }

  // clear submittedWords array after each check
  submittedWords = [];
}

document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  submittedWords = [];
  validateText();
})
```

```html
<form>
  <input name="test" type="text" value="" />
  <textarea type="text" value=""></textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```